# ggplot2 in R: why is the box plot fill colour very pale?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, boxplot, alpha-transparency

I've created box plots using `ggplot()` in R, using instructions online but the fill colour is really transparent and not showing up well compared to what it looks like on other people's plots. How can I solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Load ggplot and the mpg dataset

library(ggplot2)

data(mpg)
head(mpg)

# A tibble: 6 x 11
  manufacturer model displ  year   cyl trans      drv     cty   hwy fl    class  
  <chr>        <chr> <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>      <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>  
1 audi         a4      1.8  1999     4 auto(l5)   f        18    29 p     compact
2 audi         a4      1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) f        21    29 p     compact
3 audi         a4      2    2008     4 manual(m6) f        20    31 p     compact
4 audi         a4      2    2008     4 auto(av)   f        21    30 p     compact
5 audi         a4      2.8  1999     6 auto(l5)   f        16    26 p     compact
6 audi         a4      2.8  1999     6 manual(m5) f        18    26 p     compact
```

Set a higher `alpha = ...` inside of the call to `geom_boxplot()`. In general, `alpha = ...` refers to the opacity of a particular geom; they range from 0 to 1. Let's produce two plots. Here is one using the `mpg` dataset. I set `alpha = 0.9`, producing rather opaque boxes:

```
ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = class, y = hwy)) + 
  geom_boxplot(fill = "blue", alpha = 0.9) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: dark]

In the next plot, we set `alpha = 0.2`, which consequently produces translucent boxes:

```
ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = class, y = hwy)) + 
  geom_boxplot(fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: light]

In general, we usually adjust the transparency of a particular plot to *down-weight* less salient observations or to avoid instances of over-plotting. I would argue a lower transparency works well in this setting. It accentuates the contours of the boxes and draws attention to the median within each categorical group.